# JSP, Spring - assign to object selected value from drop down box

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In JSP in drop down box I have a list of countries. Selected country I should assign to "Organization" object as an object "Country".

JSP:

```
<select name="country">
   <c:forEach var="country" items="${countries}" >
     <option value="${country}">
          <c:out value="${country.name}" />
     </option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Model, Organisation:

```
@Entity
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    //I should assign "Country" object to this field
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="country")
    private Country country;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private Long market_cap;

    public Organization(Integer id, String name, Country country, String address, String phone, Long market_cap) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.market_cap = market_cap;
    }

    public Organization() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Long getMarket_cap() {
        return market_cap;
    }

    public void setMarketCap(Long market_cap) {
        this.market_cap = market_cap;
    }

}
```

Model, Country:

```
@Entity
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id_country;
    private String name;
    private String isocode;

    public Country() {
    }

    public Country(Integer id_country, String name, String isocode) {
        this.id_country = id_country;
        this.name = name;
        this.isocode = isocode;
    }

    public Integer getId_country() {
        return id_country;
    }

    public void setId_country(Integer id_country) {
        this.id_country = id_country;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIsocode() {
        return isocode;
    }

    public void setIsocode(String isocode) {
        this.isocode = isocode;
    }
}
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addOrganization() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add");
    Organization organization = new Organization();
    modelAndView.addObject("organization", organization);
    List<Country> countries = countryService.listOfCountries();
    modelAndView.addObject("countries", countries);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

I have Bad Request error.

Comment: How is your request defined (how is your url endpoint)? I thing you send your Form with method POST, but your Handler Mapping expects GET.